Pass multiple PrincipleIDs to the roleassignments/addroleassignment endpoint inside SharePoint Online REST API
I have a cloud flow, which get a semi-colon separated string containing Office 365 security groups names. Then I build an array after splitting the string.
After that for each group name I get the group PrincipleID, then i add the group to the item permission with Read role. Sometimes this array contains 5 group names. So I will assign each group to the list item separately, which might not be the best approach.  So I am looking to pass all the 5 group PrincipleIDs at once to SharePoint.
So is there a way to pass a list of groups' principle Ids to the roleassignments/addroleassignment end point, instead of just passing single Principe ID? keeping in mind that all groups will have Read.
Here is my current flow:-


so is there a way to pass multiple Principleds inside this Uri:-
_api/web/lists('*ListName*')/items(*ItemNumber*)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(PrincipalId=*PrincipleID*,roleDefId=1073741826)

EDIT
I tried this inside Power Automate Send Http Request to SharePoint to doa Batch request:-

but i got this error:-
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "Cannot find resource for the request $batch.\r\nclientRequestId: 38ee4283-cbe9-4544-b58e-20be4dff6677\r\nserviceRequestId: 60405aa1-c0f6-a000-176a-18a93b116d0f",
  "source": "https://**.sharepoint.com/_api/$batch",
  "errors": [
    "-1",
    "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException"
  ]
}

EDIT-2
After i changed the main method from GET to POST as follow:-

i got this error:-
A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'multipart/mixed' matches the content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.

and here is the Body text i am passing:-
--batch_1234
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_1234

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://**.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('GroupNamePrincipleID')/items(1)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(PrincipalId=2047,roleDefId=1073741826) HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://**.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('GroupNamePrincipleID')/items(2)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(PrincipalId=2047,roleDefId=1073741826) HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://**.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('GroupNamePrincipleID')/items(3)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(PrincipalId=2047,roleDefId=1073741826) HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234--
--batch_1234--

EDIT-3
I added Content-Type: application/json, but still the same error on the Content-Types
--batch_1234
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="changeset_1234"
Host: https://**.sharepoint.com
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://**.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('GroupNamePrincipleID')/items(1)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(PrincipalId=2047,roleDefId=1073741826) HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://**.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('GroupNamePrincipleID')/items(2)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(PrincipalId=2047,roleDefId=1073741826) HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://mohannadghawi.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('GroupNamePrincipleID')/items(3)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(PrincipalId=2047,roleDefId=1073741826) HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234--
--batch_1234--

EDIT-4
This worked for me :-
--batch_1234
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="changeset_1234"

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://**.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('GroupNamePrincipleID')/items(1)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(PrincipalId=2047,roleDefId=1073741826) HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://**.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('GroupNamePrincipleID')/items(2)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(PrincipalId=2047,roleDefId=1073741826) HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://**.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('GroupNamePrincipleID')/items(3)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(PrincipalId=2047,roleDefId=1073741826) HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234--

--batch_1234--


Yes, with SharePoint Online REST API you can batch multiple requests in one call. For example, you can call multiple GET to read data, or multiple POST or DELETE to edit or delete items on a SharePoint list.
References:

Make batch requests with the REST APIs
Batch Processing (OData Version 3.0)

Sample from Microsoft Learn:
POST https://fabrikam.sharepoint.com/_api/$batch HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_e3b6819b-13c3-43bb-85b2-24b14122fed1

--batch_e3b6819b-13c3-43bb-85b2-24b14122fed1
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET https://fabrikam.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('Composed%20Looks')/items?$select=Title HTTP/1.1

--batch_e3b6819b-13c3-43bb-85b2-24b14122fed1
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET https://fabrikam.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('User%20Information%20List')/items?$select=Title HTTP/1.1

--batch_e3b6819b-13c3-43bb-85b2-24b14122fed1--

In Power Automate, with the action Send an HTTP request to SharePoint you can achieve what you are requesting. The prerequisite is to concatenate your ids with a Select or Compose (+ join method).
The parameters should be something like that:

Site address: https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site
Method: POST
URI: _api/$batch
Headers: ContentType multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_1234

Body:
--batch_1234
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_1234

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Your-List')/items(123)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(PrincipalId=1,roleDefId=1073741826) HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Your-List')/items(123)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(PrincipalId=2,roleDefId=1073741826) HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Your-List')/items(123)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(PrincipalId=3,roleDefId=1073741826) HTTP/1.1

--changeset_1234--
--batch_1234--

Screenshots of the results (in this sample, I give 3 permissions to the same user, but you can give the same permission to 3 users, it's working the same way)



Usefull article: Writing batch SharePoint API calls in Power Automate

can you please check my edit, i am getting an error when trying to do a Batch inside power automate

404 means the item does not exists. Are you sure that POST and https are on the same line with just one space? Also it’s _api not /_api.

thanks again for your help.. yes the Post and Https has only one space . for the Uril i added "/" because if i define the Uri as "_api/$batch" i will get this error:-

{   "status": 404,   "message": "Cannot find resource for the request $batch.\r\nclientRequestId: 3e883d1b-8026-48cb-9c4b-19cd288c95be\r\nserviceRequestId: de695aa1-8077-9000-f80e-b11760e2a7d1",   "source": "https://****.sharepoint.com/_api/$batch",   "errors": [     "-1",     "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException"   ] } any advice? Thanks

now i noticed that my Method was define as Get while i am doing 3 post requests, so i changed the method to be "Post" and now i am geting this error instead A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'multipart/mixed' matches the content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'. -

The batch request must be POST but your capture shows GET. Be more careful when reading my answer.

ok after changing the Method to be POST , i got a new error A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'multipart/mixed' matches the content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8' if you can check my EDIT-2 please

appreciate your help, i added this extra content-type as per my Edit-3 but still the same error

I recreate the same flow and it's working fine (statut code 200, with no error). Check my screenshots.

finally it worked after i remove some white spaces as per Edit-4 thanks a lot for your help + i was passing the ContentType , where i change it as Content-Type
